# Excel VBA query by date to my Mysql database (linux)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to query to our MySql database(linux base) through Excel VBA script but every time my query have "dates" condition, I get an error

> runtime error '-2147217900(80040e14)'

Which I think is because of date format issue.

I can execute same command in MySql workbench without any error but didn't work from Excel VBA.

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT run.id, dut.pca, dut.asy, dut.serialNumber, run.station, run.testbedId, run.startTime, run.endTime," & _
"run.result FROM Mfg.run" & _
"Left JOIN Mfg.dut ON Mfg.run.dutId = dut.id" & _
"WHERE run.endTime between '2017-10-26' and '2017-10-27' " & _
"order by run.endTime asc;"
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the concatenated string and running that against the db. As is, there will be no space between `Mfg.run` and `Left` and also between `dut.id` and `WHERE`

Comment: Thanks SearchAndResQ, It works perfectly when i use concatenate =CONCATENATE("'",A1, "'", " ", "and", " ", "'", B1, "' ") SQLQuery = "SELECT run.id, dut.pca, dut.asy, dut.serialNumber, run.station, run.testbedId, run.startTime, run.endTime, " & _ "run.result FROM Mfg.run " & _ "LEFT JOIN Mfg.dut ON Mfg.run.dutId = dut.id " & _ "WHERE run.endTime BETWEEN " & [$C$1] & "ORDER BY run.endTime ASC;"